# Dart String Normalization

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I normalize locale characters like Turkish "İĞŞÇ" to "igsc" in Dart-Flutter?

```
var string = "İĞŞÇ".normalize();
print(string)
```

```
Output: igsc
```

Is there a way to do this like above?

Comment: you can use this  : https://pub.dev/packages/diacritic

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for the compiler to tell that `"İĞŞÇ" = "igsc"`
they have different bits combination so you can't do so unfortunately automatically.

unless you declare in your code that for example

```
"Ğ":"g"
```

and so on...
and when the compiler finds the special character it will converted to its declared equivalent.